# Is it possible to have a bash script know the correct $HOME without sudo -H?

Tags: bash

I have a script that may be used as root (`sudo ./script.sh`) and if so, I need access to the root's $HOME.

I can do both of the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
ThisUser=$(id -u -n)
REALHOME="~$ThisUser"
eval "cd $REALHOME"
```

or with `sudo -H script.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $HOME
```

Is there a solution that both
a. Doesn't require 'eval'
b. Doesn't require telling the user to use sudo -H.

?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `echo $HOME` (and only when that fails, use some more fancy things).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet, IMO, is to call the POSIX API for retrieving it.  (If you know that /etc/passwd holds the user, you can use grep-cut or sed or awk to retrieve it, but this isn't portable to NIS-based systems or many other centralised user management setups.)  Of course, you're in shell, so you'd need some way to get it.  Luckily, that's not too hard:

```
perl -MUser::pwent -e 'print getpw($<)->dir'
```

This is not golfed, it's longer than it needs to be just to make it somewhat readable.  Understanding that is easier than `perl -e 'print ((getpwuid($>))[7])'` :-)